JSP page field Id problem after Struts upgrade from 2.5.26 to 2.5.30
After we upgraded Struts from 2.5.26 to 2.5.30 by replacing Struts core jar file, it looks like our JSP page field id generation performed by Struts is different than previous Struts. For example, we have a field name like this in our JSP:
<input type="checkbox" name="seqResponseMap['seq1_decision_outcome_partially_favorable_chk__01']" ...

When it is translated into a html page at runtime by Struts 2.5.30, it looks like this:
<input type="checkbox" name="seqResponseMap['seq1_decision_outcome_partially_favorable_chk__01']" value="01" id="SequentialOne_seqResponseMap__seq1_decision_outcome_partially_favorable_chk__01__" ...

So it looks like Struts replaced both "'" and "[" with "_" in field id from original field name. That's not how it worked in previous Struts before 2.5.30.
In our JavaScript code we expect field id looks like SequentialOne_seqResponseMap['seq1_decision_outcome_partially_favorable_chk__01'] based on its field name so it is not working any more.
Is this how it is supposed to work in Struts 2.5.30 or we miss something during the upgrade?
Thank you very much for your help.

You have used a very complex value for the id of the input box. So, Struts has simplified it.

The id attribute in form tags is automatically generated. But it can be overridden if you specify HTML ID attribute.
ID assignment:

All form tags automatically assign an ID to the control, but the ID can be overridden if needed.
Forms  The default ID is the action name. For example, “updateAddress”.
Controls    The default ID is the form’s name concatenated with the tag name. For example, “updateAddress_postalCode”.

To override the value of the ID attribute you can use altSyntax.

The altSyntax changes the behavior of how tags are interpreted. Instead of evaluating each tag parameter against the value stack and needing single quotes to mark string literals, only marked expressions are evaluated.

So, you can use something like
<s:checkbox 
  name="seqResponseMap['seq1_decision_outcome_partially_favorable_chk__01']"
  id="seqResponseMap[%{'seq1_decision_outcome_partially_favorable_chk__01'}]" 
...
/>



We can't put id there in JSP because it is used inside an iterator such as radio buttons. Each single item is generated at runtime even they all share the same element name.

How do I know what is used in your JSP if you didn't post a code?
